# Vimeo embeded videos sending HTTP requests on HTTPS page

Tags: http, https, vimeo, vimeo-player

I use a site that has SSL with Extended Validation enabled. In other words, when a user accesses my site, the address tool bar becomes green with the name of my company showing that it's secure. If my page gets any resources from HTTP page, I lost the green status and it becomes an ugly orange with exclamation mark.

The problem is that my page has a Vimeo video embedded (with iFrame). When you access it, the address tool bar is green but if you pass your mouse over the video, it becomes orange! After some investigation, it was detected that a http site is called (http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/...).

Searching google show me the following answer from Vimeo:

https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:98803

In other words, it's NEVER going to be fixed :(

Is there any way we can BLOCK this call from this embeded video?

Answer (score 2):

That call is the actual video file, so you wouldn't want to block it. We are working with our CDN to get HTTPS video delivery working, and we're very close.

Comment: Do you have an ETA on that? I really REALLY wish I would have known this would be a problem before signing up for pro account :( We display all our videos over https to IE users and it displays a huge hideous warning

Comment: @Tallboy Hopefully really soon. We're held up because we're seeing lots of playback errors in Chrome. We're actively working with our CDN on a solution.

Comment: We are having the same problem too, hope this will be ready soon. Thanks!  The documentation already seemed to imply HTTPS embeds worked...

Comment: well? any progress with the HTTPS Vimeo?

Comment: @Bergkamp it has been fully supported for some time now

Comment: @BradDougherty There's still a problem, because the secure page is requesting (non-ssl) tracking .gif files from http://b.scorecardresearch.com . This breaks the integrity of any page served over SSL as soon as Vimeo videos are watched.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have covered most of the question - in the absence of Vimeo fixing the problem, the only practical way to avoid this is to proxy the vimeo access via your own site and rewrite the content passing through to change the URLs to point to your (HTTPS) proxy - which is hardly a very appropriate solution.